# Incrementing Variable in v-for Loop by Amount Returned from Method

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a table that uses v-for to loop through an object of days returned from using axios. I've given the ability to manipulate a variety of booleans on each row which change some calculated values in some columns. What I need is to calculate the total of these columns in a bottom row accounting for changes from the values in the rest of the table.

I've tried calling on a method to do something like this.total.b2cTotal += someNumber; but it bugs out the page.

the code

```html
            <table v-if="userSelect != 0" class="w-full text-md bg-white shadow-md rounded mb-4 reports text-sm">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th v-if="userSelect == 'all'" class="text-left p-3 px-5">User Name</th>
                        <th class="text-left p-3 px-5">Day</th>
                        <th class="text-left p-3 px-5">Show Code</th>
                        <th class="text-left p-3 px-5">Day Type</th>
                        <th class="text-left p-3 px-5">Sch. (hrs)</th>
                        <th class="text-left p-3 px-5">Actual</th>
                        <th class="text-left p-3 px-5">Reg</th>
                        <th class="text-left p-3 px-5">OT</th>
                        <th class="text-left p-3 px-5">1.5x</th>
                        <th class="text-left p-3 px-5">DT</th>
                        <th class="text-left p-3 px-5">Rate</th>
                        <th class="text-left p-3 px-5">B2C?</th>
                        <th class="text-left p-3 px-5">OT Apr?</th>
                        <th class="text-left p-3 px-5">OT B2C?</th>
                        <th class="text-left p-3 px-5">PD?</th>
                        <th class="text-left p-3 px-5">PD $</th>
                        <th class="text-left p-3 px-5">TRV?</th>
                        <th class="text-left p-3 px-5">B2C Labor</th>
                        <th class="text-left p-3 px-5">B2C OT</th>
                        <th class="text-left p-3 px-5">FT Labor</th>
                        <th class="text-left p-3 px-5">FT OT</th>
                        <th class="text-left p-3 px-5">Worker Paid</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="text-center" v-for="(day,index) in userDays" :key="index">
                        <td v-if="userSelect == 'all'" class="p-3 px-5">{{ day.userName }}</td>
                        <td class="p-3 px-5">{{ day.date }}</td>
                        <td class="p-3 px-5">{{ day.projectCode }}</td>
                        <td class="p-3 px-5">tbd</td>
                        <td class="p-3 px-5">{{ day.scheduledHours }}</td>
                        <td class="p-3 px-5 font-bold">{{ day.actualHours }}</td>
                        <td class="p-3 px-5">{{ day.regHours }}</td>
                        <td class="p-3 px-5 font-bold">{{ day.otHours }}</td>
                        <td class="p-3 px-5">{{ day.timeAndAHalfHours }}</td>
                        <td class="p-3 px-5">{{ day.doubleTimeHours }}</td>
                        <td class="p-3 px-5">${{ day.costRate }}</td>
                        <td class="p-3 px-5"> <!-- billable to client -->
                            <img v-if="day.billable == 1" @click="(toggleDayBoolean(day.dayID,'billable','disable'),day.billable = 0)" src="https://img.icons8.com/ultraviolet/22/000000/checked-2.png">
                            <img v-if="day.billable == 0" @click="(toggleDayBoolean(day.dayID,'billable','enable'),day.billable = 1)" src="https://img.icons8.com/officel/22/000000/stop.png">
                        </td>
                        <td class="p-3 px-5"> <!-- over time -->
                            <img v-if="day.otApproved == 1" @click="(toggleDayBoolean(day.dayID,'otApproved','disable'),day.otApproved = 0)" src="https://img.icons8.com/ultraviolet/22/000000/checked-2.png">
                            <img v-if="day.otApproved == 0" @click="(toggleDayBoolean(day.dayID,'otApproved','enable'),day.otApproved = 1)" src="https://img.icons8.com/officel/22/000000/stop.png">
                        </td>
                        <td class="p-3 px-5"> <!-- over time -->
                            <img v-if="day.otBillable == 1" @click="(toggleDayBoolean(day.dayID,'otBillable','disable'),day.otBillable = 0)" src="https://img.icons8.com/ultraviolet/22/000000/checked-2.png">
                            <img v-if="day.otBillable == 0" @click="(toggleDayBoolean(day.dayID,'otBillable','enable'),day.otBillable = 1)" src="https://img.icons8.com/officel/22/000000/stop.png">
                        </td>
                        <td class="p-3 px-5"> <!-- per diem -->
                            <img v-if="day.pdApproved == 1" @click="(toggleDayBoolean(day.dayID,'pdApproved','disable'),day.pdApproved = 0)" src="https://img.icons8.com/ultraviolet/22/000000/checked-2.png">
                            <img v-if="day.pdApproved == 0" @click="(toggleDayBoolean(day.dayID,'pdApproved','enable'),day.pdApproved = 1)" src="https://img.icons8.com/officel/22/000000/stop.png">
                        </td>
                        <td class="p-3 px-5">${{ day.pdAmount }}</td>
                        <td class="p-3 px-5"> <!-- travel -->
                            <img v-if="day.travel == 1" @click="(toggleDayBoolean(day.dayID,'travel','disable'),day.travel = 0)" src="https://img.icons8.com/ultraviolet/22/000000/checked-2.png">
                            <img v-if="day.travel == 0" @click="(toggleDayBoolean(day.dayID,'travel','enable'),day.travel = 1)" src="https://img.icons8.com/officel/22/000000/stop.png">
                        </td>
                        <td class="p-3 px-5">${{ costDistributor('b2c',day).b2c }} <div v-text="addTo()"></div></td>
                        <td class="p-3 px-5">${{ costDistributor('b2cOT',day).b2cOT }}</td>
                        <td class="p-3 px-5">${{ costDistributor('ft',day).ft }}</td>
                        <td class="p-3 px-5">${{ costDistributor('ftOT',day).ftOT }}</td>
                        <td class="p-3 px-5">
                            <strong>${{ day.totalCost + day.pdAmount }}</strong>&nbsp;
                            <span class="view-icon"><a target="dayView" :href='"/tracker/resources/days/"+day.dayID' class="cursor-pointer text-70 hover:text-primary mr-3" data-testid="projects-items-3-view-button" dusk="10-view-button" title="View">
                                <img src="https://img.icons8.com/ultraviolet/40/000000/visible.png"></a></span>
                            <!-- <span class="lock-icon"><a href="" class="cursor-pointer text-70 hover:text-primary mr-3" data-testid="projects-items-3-view-button" dusk="10-view-button" title="View">
                                <img src="https://img.icons8.com/ultraviolet/40/000000/lock.png"></a></span> -->
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr v-if="userSelect!=0" class="font-bold text-lg">
                        <td v-if="userSelect == 'all'" class="p-3 px-5">{{  }}</td>
                        <td class="p-3 px-5">{{  }}</td>
                        <td class="p-3 px-5">{{  }}</td>
                        <td class="p-3 px-5">{{  }}</td>
                        <td class="p-3 px-5">{{ finalTotal(userSelect,'scheduledHours') }} hrs</td>
                        <td class="p-3 px-5">{{ finalTotal(userSelect,'actualHours') }} hrs</td>
                        <td class="p-3 px-5">{{  }}</td>
                        <td class="p-3 px-5">{{ finalTotal(userSelect,'otHours') }} hrs</td>
                        <td class="p-3 px-5">{{ finalTotal(userSelect,'timeAndAHalfHours') }} hrs</td>
                        <td class="p-3 px-5">{{ finalTotal(userSelect,'doubleTimeHours') }} hrs</td>
                        <td class="p-3 px-5">{{  }}</td>
                        <td class="p-3 px-5">{{  }}</td>
                        <td class="p-3 px-5">{{  }}</td>
                        <td class="p-3 px-5">{{  }}</td>
                        <td class="p-3 px-5">{{  }}</td>
                        <td class="p-3 px-5">${{ finalTotal(userSelect,'pdAmount') }}</td>
                        <td class="p-3 px-5">{{  }}</td>
                        <td class="p-3 px-5">${{ addToTotal('show','b2c',0) }}</td>
                        <td class="p-3 px-5">${{ finalTotal(userSelect,'b2cOT') }}</td>
                        <td class="p-3 px-5">${{ finalTotal(userSelect,'ft') }}</td>
                        <td class="p-3 px-5">${{ finalTotal(userSelect,'ftOT') }}</td>
                        <td class="p-3 px-5">${{ finalTotal(userSelect,'totalCost') }}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
</table>
```

*I added in the finalTotal code though it's irrelevant to what I'm trying to solve*

```js
methods: {
        /**
         * distribute costs to company or client
         * 
         * @param string
         * @param App\CrewCallReports@getUserDays object
         * 
         * @return object
         */
        costDistributor(type,day){
            let totals = {
                b2c: 0,
                b2cOT: 0,
                ft: 0,
                ftOT: 0,
                b2cTotal: 0
            };

            switch(type){
                case 'b2c':
                    if(day.billable && day.regHours == 'straight'){
                        // if straight time then bill actual hours
                        if(day.billable){
                            totals.b2c = day.costRate * day.actualHours;
                            totals.b2cTotal += totals.b2c;
                        }
                        // if pd approved then add it
                        if(day.pdApproved){
                            totals.b2c += day.pdAmount;
                            totals.b2cTotal += day.pdAmount;
                        }
                    }else if(day.billable && day.regHours != 'straight'){
                        // if not straight time but billable to client
                        if(day.billable){
                            totals.b2c = day.costRate * day.regularHours;
                            totals.b2cTotal += totals.b2c;
                        }
                        // if pd approved then add it
                        if(day.pdApproved){
                            totals.b2c += day.pdAmount;
                            totals.b2cTotal += day.pdAmount;
                        }
                    }else if(!day.billable){
                        // no labor charged to client
                        totals.b2c = 0;
                        totals.b2cTotal += totals.b2c;
                        // in case pd applies but regular labor doesn't (weird case)
                        if(day.pdApproved){
                            totals.b2c += day.pdAmount;
                            totals.b2cTotal += day.pdAmount;
                        }
                    }
                    // we need to add travel into this formula
                break;

                case 'ft':
                    if(!day.billable && day.regHours == 'straight'){
                        // add base hour cost
                        if(!day.billable){
                            totals.ft = day.costRate * day.actualHours;
                        }
                        // add per diem if applicable
                        if(!day.pdApproved){
                            totals.ft += day.pdAmount;
                        }
                    }else if(!day.billable && day.regHours != 'straight'){
                        // add base cost if not straight time
                        if(!day.billable){
                            totals.ft = day.costRate * day.regularHours;
                        }
                        // add per diem if applicable
                        if(!day.pdApproved){
                            totals.ft += day.pdAmount;
                        }
                    }else if(day.billable){
                        // labor charged to client
                        totals.ft = 0;
                        if(!day.pdApproved){
                            totals.ft += day.pdAmount;
                        }
                    }
                break;

                case 'b2cOT':
                    // if OT is billable to client and approved
                    if(day.otBillable && day.otApproved){
                        totals.b2cOT = (day.costRate * day.timeAndAHalfHours * 1.5) + (day.costRate * day.doubleTimeHours * 2);
                    }else{
                        // all other cases don't bill client at all
                        totals.b2cOT = 0;
                    }
                break;

                case 'ftOT':
                    // if OT is not billable to client but approved
                    if(!day.otBillable && day.otApproved){
                        totals.ftOT = (day.costRate * day.timeAndAHalfHours * 1.5) + (day.costRate * day.doubleTimeHours * 2);
                    }else{
                        totals.ftOT = 0;
                    }
                break;
            }

            return totals;
        },

        getUserDays(e){
            // grab the days for this user and spit it to the table
            axios.get(this.userURI+e.target.value+'/days').then(response=>{
                this.userDays = response.data.days;
            });

            this.userID = e.target.value;
        },
        finalTotal($userID,$field){
            // set user ID to 0 if all are selected for lookup
            if($userID == 'all'){
                $userID = 0;
            }

            let days = this.userDays;

            function sumFinder(id,field) {
                return days.reduce((sum, e) => {
                    if(id == 0){
                        sum += e[field];
                        return sum;
                    }else{
                        e.userID == id ? (sum += e[field]) : (sum += 0);
                        return sum;
                    }
                }, 0);
            }

            // Create our number formatter.
            var formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
                currency: 'USD',
            });

            return formatter.format(sumFinder($userID,$field));
        },
}
```

Comment: you haven't included the code for the `findTotal` method

Comment: addToTotal is the one I'm trying to solve as finalTotal pulls the formula from an API call. I added it above to show. I'm thinking I need to possibly add each calculated day row to an array and use the .reduce function to get the formula but don't know how to pull it off correctly.

Comment: No dont do that! To sum it up: onrender you force a rerender === while(true)never stop. Take the axios response and compute  the desired values in computed ;)

Comment: @Estradiaz I'm needing to calculate the sum of the v-for loop as there are calculations I'm doing on the front-end since things are updating real-time. I move numbers between columns based on booleans and didn't want to keep requesting from the back-end but can if necessary.

Comment: You have a missconception of render and frontend ... Vue is always on the front-end even if SSR. Moreover is vue data driven. Prepare data and render it accordingly in the template/render function.